# Alternative to private setters in Automatic properties

Tags: c#, .net, oop

If you're not supposed to use private setters for automatic properties (bad practice) then how can I set it privately from within the class and still expose it with just a get to the public? (lets say I want to set it at the constructor level but still allow it to be public by get)?

example class:

```
public class Car
{
    //set the property via constructor
    public SomeClass(LicensePlate license)
    {
         License = license
    }

    public LicensePlate License{get; private set;} // bad practice
}
```

Comment: Can you cite where you heard that private setters are bad for automatic properties? First time I've heard that.

Comment: I know that private or otherwise non-accessible/missing `get` is bad practice, but I don't know why `private set` would be bad.

Answer (score 4):

You convert the property to one with a backing field and no setter.

```
public class Car
{
    LicensePlate _license;

    public Car(LicensePlate license)
    {
        _license = license;
    }

    public LicensePlate License
    {
        get { return _license; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna use the old style though :).  Why is setting the setter privately even bad practice in the first place?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict It's not. Can you show me why you think so? The only reason which makes me prefer properties with no setter and backing field is that Intellisense in VS doesn't have a different icon for the former as it does for the latter -- So you may not know, by simply looking at the icons, if an auto-property has a public setter/getter.